# PL/SQL embedded insert into table that may not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I much prefer using this 'embedded' style inserts in a pl/sql block (opposed to the execute immediate style dynamic sql - where you have to delimit quotes etc).

```
-- a contrived example
PROCEDURE CreateReport( customer IN VARCHAR2, reportdate IN DATE )
BEGIN

   -- drop table, create table with explicit column list
   CreateReportTableForCustomer;

   INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE 
   VALUES ( customer, reportdate );
END;
/
```

The problem here is that oracle checks if 'temp_table' exists and that it has the correct number of colunms and throws a compile error if it doesn't exist.

So I was wondering if theres any way round that?!  Essentially I want to use a placeholder for the table name to trick oracle into not checking if the table exists.

**EDIT:**

I should have mentioned that a user is able to execute any 'report' (as above). A mechanism that will execute an arbitrary query but always write to the temp_table ( in the user's schema).  Thus each time the report proc is run it drops the temp_table and recreates it with, most probably, a different column list.

Comment: You should be able to do this with precompiler directives. To get started, check here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28428/pcoafemb.htm

Comment: @Guru: I thought the problem was that the table would not exist at compile time but would exist at run time, by the time the insert statement is called. How would precompiler directives help?

Comment: That is what execute immediate is for (among other things). No matter if you like it or not.

Comment: @Jens Schauder: ...hence my "execute immediate" answer. ;)

Comment: I'd like to know more about why you want to do operations on a table that doesn't exist. Can you provide a more concrete example? Otherwise, I believe the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE solution is best.

Comment: What happens when a user wants to run two different reports at the same time?

Comment: The front end application won't allow them to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a dynamic SQL statement to insert into the maybe-existent temp_table, and then catch and handle the exception that occurs when the table doesn't exist.

Example:

```
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO '||TEMP_TABLE_NAME||'  VALUES ( :customer, :reportdate )' using customer, reportdate;
```

Note that having the table name vary in a dynamic SQL statement is not very good, so if you ensure the table names stay the same, that would be best.

Comment: yep, you are right. Thats what execute immediate is for and that is what I ended up using.  thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should be using a [global temporary table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm#i16096) (GTT).  These are permanent table structures that hold temporary data for an Oracle session.  Many different sessions can insert data into the same GTT, and each will only be able to see their own data.  The data is automatically deleted either on COMMIT or when the session ends, according to the GTT's definition.

You create the GTT (once only) like this:

```
create globabal temporary table my_gtt
(customer number, report_date date) 
on commit delete/preserve* rows;
```

* delete as applicable

Then your programs can just use it like any other table - the only difference being it always begins empty for your session.

Comment: I don't know, put populating a GTT in a stored procedure and running a table function against it isn't a bad idea.  It's a perfectly valid implementation provided the data in the OP's TEMP_TABLE doesn't need to survive or be visible outside the scope of the current session.  It's certainly a better idea than having the PL/SQL drop and create tables.  My suspicion is this is a SQL Server development pattern which isn't really applicable to Oracle.

Comment: i like the idea, but it wouldn't work since (the bit i didn't mention - sorry!) the temp_table will change from report to report.

Comment: How does a temporary table solves the problem stated? When a temporary table does not exist, PL/SQL code referencing it still doesn't compile.

Comment: My point was that a GTT should always exist, that dropping and recreating GTTs on the fly is not their intended use.  I know now from a comment above that that doesn't solve Richard's problem, but it could have.

Comment: @Jens: a temporary table is created once and never dropped. However, the limitation is that their structure is static.

Answer (score 1):

Using GTTs are much preferable to dropping/recreating tables on the fly - if your application needs a different structure for each report, I strongly suggest you work out all the different structures that each report needs, and create separate GTTs as needed by each, instead of creating ordinary tables at runtime.

That said, if this is just not feasible (and I've seen good examples when it's not, e.g. in a system that supports a wide range of ad-hoc requests from users), you'll have to go with the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` approach.